# Upload an image to two different paths

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload, image-uploading

How to upload an image and save it in two different folders, `./imgup/web/data_dinamis/` and `./imgup/web/video/` ?

My code to upload image :

```
$config['upload_path'] = './imgup/web/data_dinamis/'; 
$config['upload_path'] = './imgup/web/video/'; 
$config['allowed_types'] = '*'; 
$config['file_name'] = $nama_baru;

$this->load->library('upload',$config);
$this->upload->do_upload('file');
$this->upload->display_errors();
$berita = array(
 'user_id' =>  $this->session->userdata('user')->user_id,
 'kategori_id' => $this->input->post('kategori_id'),
 'judul' => $this->input->post('judul'),
 'gambar' =>  $nama_baru,
);
```

All images are saved only in `'./imgup/web/data_dinamis/'`, but not in `'./imgup/web/video/'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest would be to use `->do_upload()` for each of the path you might want to upload to:

```
$p1='./imgup/web/data_dinamis/';
$p2='./imgup/web/video/';

//create an array of pathes:
$p=array($p1, $p2);

// get length of array
$c=count($p);

// loop through
for ($i=0;$i<$c;$i++){    
  $config['upload_path'] =$p[$i];
  $config['allowed_types'] = '*'; 
  $config['file_name'] = $nama_baru;

  $this->load->library('upload',$config);
  $this->upload->initialize($config);
  $this->upload->do_upload('file');
  $this->upload->display_errors();
}

$berita = array(
   'user_id' =>  $this->session->userdata('user')->user_id,
   'kategori_id' => $this->input->post('kategori_id'),
   'judul' => $this->input->post('judul'),
   'gambar' =>  $nama_baru,
);
```

**note:** after `$this->load->library('upload',$config);` use `$this->upload->initialize($config);` 
This is useful if you auto-load the class, see docs [here](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html?highlight=initialize#setting-preferences)

Comment: the all images saved only in './imgup/web/data_dinamis/', not with './imgup/web/video/' too

Comment: try with `$this->upload->initialize($config);` also check if 2nd path is writable

Comment: ITS WORKING, BIG THANKS TO YOU:)