# Codeigniter File Upload Permit Only For Images not For Others

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

I have to file upload operation consecutive, first for images like gif|jpg|jpeg|png|svg and the second psd|rar|zip|doc|word|txt|xlsx|pdf
First one is working just fine, i can upload all images but the second, i can not upload any of these types but when i try to upload image on second segment it works.

```php
if (isset($_FILES['content_images']['name'])) {
    $count_files = count($_FILES['content_images']['name']);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count_files; $i++) {
        $_FILES['image']['name'] = $_FILES['content_images']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['image']['type'] = $_FILES['content_images']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['content_images']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['image']['error'] = $_FILES['content_images']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['image']['size'] = $_FILES['content_images']['size'][$i];
        $config_images['upload_path'] = "./public/site/images/contents";
        $config_images['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png|svg';
        $config_images['max_size'] = 5000;
        $config_images['max_width'] = 7680;
        $config_images['max_height'] = 4320;
        $this->load->library("upload", $config_images);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('image')) {
            echo $this->upload->display_errors();
            exit;
        } else {
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            $path_images[] = "public/site/images/contents/".$data['file_name'];
        }
    }
}

if (isset($_FILES['content_files']['name'])) {
    $count_files=count($_FILES['content_files']['name']);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count_files; $i++) {
        $_FILES['file']['name'] = $_FILES['content_files']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['file']['type'] = $_FILES['content_files']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['content_files']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['file']['error'] = $_FILES['content_files']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['file']['size'] = $_FILES['content_files']['size'][$i];
        $config_files['upload_path'] = "./public/site/files/contents";
        $config_files['allowed_types'] = 'psd|rar|zip|doc|word|txt|xlsx|pdf';
        $config_files['max_size'] = 5000;
        $config_files['max_width'] = 7680;
        $config_files['max_height'] = 4320;
        $this->load->library("upload",$config_files);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file')) {
            foreach($path_images as $p){
                unlink($p);
            }
            echo $this->upload->display_errors();
            exit;
        } else {
            $data=$this->upload->data();
            $path_files[] = "public/site/files/contents/".$data['file_name'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57591036/2275490

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution 
For help : 
You should load the library at the top for 1 time only, and then u should initialize it inside 'if condition'.
When you load upload library and config array inside first condition, when you pass to second condition upload library had already loaded and uses the first condition's config array.

```php
$this->load->library("upload");
            if(isset($_FILES['content_images']['name'])){
                $count_files=count($_FILES['content_images']['name']);
                for($i = 0;$i<$count_files;$i++){
                    $_FILES['image']['name'] = $_FILES['content_images']['name'][$i];
                    $_FILES['image']['type'] = $_FILES['content_images']['type'][$i];
                    $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['content_images']['tmp_name'][$i];
                    $_FILES['image']['error'] = $_FILES['content_images']['error'][$i];
                    $_FILES['image']['size'] = $_FILES['content_images']['size'][$i];
                    $config_images['upload_path'] = "./public/site/images/contents";
                    $config_images['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png|svg';
                    $config_images['max_size'] = 5000;
                    $config_images['max_width'] = 7680;
                    $config_images['max_height'] = 4320;
                    $this->upload->initialize($config_images);
                    if(!$this->upload->do_upload('image')){
                        echo $this->upload->display_errors();
                        exit;
                    }else{
                        $data=$this->upload->data();
                        $path_images[] = "public/site/images/contents/".$data['file_name'];
                    }
                }
            }
            if(isset($_FILES['content_files']['name'])){
                $count_files=count($_FILES['content_files']['name']);
                for($i = 0;$i<$count_files;$i++){
                    $_FILES['file']['name'] = $_FILES['content_files']['name'][$i];
                    $_FILES['file']['type'] = $_FILES['content_files']['type'][$i];
                    $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['content_files']['tmp_name'][$i];
                    $_FILES['file']['error'] = $_FILES['content_files']['error'][$i];
                    $_FILES['file']['size'] = $_FILES['content_files']['size'][$i];
                    $config_files['upload_path'] = "./public/site/files/contents";
                    $config_files['allowed_types'] = 'psd|rar|zip|doc|word|txt|xlsx|pdf';
                    $config_files['max_size'] = 5000;
                    $config_files['max_width'] = 7680;
                    $config_files['max_height'] = 4320;
                    $this->upload->initialize($config_files);
                    if(!$this->upload->do_upload('file')){
                        foreach($path_images as $p){
                            unlink($p);
                        }
                        echo $this->upload->display_errors();
                        exit;
                    }else{
                        $data=$this->upload->data();
                        $path_files[] = "public/site/files/contents/".$data['file_name'];
                    }
                }
            }
```